# Botframework compile error TypeError: bot.dialog is not a function at Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, botframework

Hi I've been stuck on this error for the last couple of days this piece of code is taken from the Microsoft docs and when I run npm start this is the error I get

```
TypeError: bot.dialog is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Conor\Documents\_repos\Chatbot - All\Backend-Conor\index.js:54:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:
```

Code:

```js
bot.dialog('greetings', [
    // Step 1
    function(session) {
        builder.Prompts.text(session, 'Hi! What is your name?');
    },
    // Step 2
    function(session, results) {
        session.endDialog(`Hello ${ results.response }!`);
    }
]);
```

If anyone has any idea why I get this error or what Im doing wrong it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: `bot` should be an instance of `UniversalBot`. Can you show the code you're using to define `bot`?

Comment: I'm using the out of the box QnA maker bot and this is how it defines the bot  const bot = new QnABot();

Comment: Please provide a link to the bot you're talking about. Also seriously consider using Bot Builder v4 instead of v3. https://blog.botframework.com/2019/06/07/v3-bot-broadcast-message/

Comment: I've rebuilt it in v4 of the bot framework

Comment: That's excellent. Would you like to post that as an answer so you can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code above is outdated since Microsoft bot framework is pulling support for this SDK. I switched over to SDK 4, Documentation can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/?view=azure-bot-service-4.0 and if you haven't migrated your bot over here is how: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/migration/migration-about?view=azure-bot-service-4.0